# Alexa-Auto-SDK cannot find autovoicechrome.aar

Tags: android, alexa-skills-kit, alexa-auto-sdk

I am trying to build sample app (apk) for alexa-auto-sdk. I am facing issues when building. the error i'm getting is.

```
    FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':alexa-auto-app:dataBindingMergeDependencyArtifactsLocalRelease'.
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':alexa-auto-app:localReleaseRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not find :autovoicechrome:.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - file:/home/chetan/Projects/Amazon_Alexa/alexa-auto-sdk/aacs/android/sample-app/alexa-auto-app/libs/autovoicechrome.aar
       - file:/home/chetan/Projects/Amazon_Alexa/alexa-auto-sdk/aacs/android/app-components/alexa-auto-voice-ui/libs/autovoicechrome.aar
       - file:/home/chetan/Projects/Amazon_Alexa/alexa-auto-sdk/aacs/android/app-components/alexa-auto-voice-interaction/libs/autovoicechrome.aar
     Required by:
         project :alexa-auto-app > project :alexa-auto-voice-ui
```

I cloned in version 4.0 as I was facing issues when building with 4.1.

This is the README.md for sample app
https://github.com/alexa/alexa-auto-sdk/blob/4.0/aacs/android/sample-app/README.md

Please help with any information that you might have related to this.

Answer (score 0):

You should request this aar from Amazone support.